# How to combine all the packages of the eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, merge, package

As I need to develop java, php, c++, I use several eclipse packages.

so I try to simple to copy several packages into one, and then I use these option to start the eclipse:
  1. -clean
  2. osgi.checkConfiguration=true

but it doesn't work, I only find the last copied packages after the IDE start.

Comment: What do you mean by copy all the packages into one?  Did you download the Eclipse version for Java and the one for PHP, etc?

Comment: Yes, I download:eclipse-helios-SR2-win32.rar
eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32.zip
eclipse-javascript-helios-SR2-win32.zip
eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.zip
eclipse-php-helios-SR2-win32.zip
eclipse-SDK-3.6.2-win32.zip   and extract them into one folder.

Comment: See my answer, there is a far less chaotic way to do it.  You only need one of the main packages.

Comment: Because the Network is not good in our country, I want to combine them cleanly and redistribution it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From luxsie:
How to merge several setup packages of Eclipse?

Whom this is for?
The ones that can not hold back their temper any longer when trying to install another Eclipse function package. Right the installation speed from some countries is too slow to bear, also the Equinox P2 always try to connect the Download.Eclipse.org. Much to damn.. when your Internet connection closed or reset all of a sudden and got all downloaded files broken. Also OSGi based Eclipse plugins is chaos -- always have some conflict errors.
Oh that is another problem..

Do the following steps:

1 Download the Install Packages that you need from www.eclipse.org. Also please remember verify to see if that is correct package. I choosed J2EE with C/C++.

2 Unpack one package with uncompress softwares, such as 7-zip and WinRAR. unzip all the files to a directory you wanna install to. for example "D:\Eclipse\".

3 open Configurations. Files "\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.source\source.info" and "\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info" in the installation directory is the ones that need to be merged. also you need "\configuration\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml".

4 open the other packages and fetch their configuration files, and merge files.

to Bundles.info:
Open the bundle.info with any Functional Text Editor, copy all text begin from the line after "#version={Number}" and paste it to another. [{Number} means any Integer number.]

to Source.info:
Similiar with what you did with the bundle.info. If not modified, that line should be the 3rd line in the text file.

to Platform.xml:
Open the file, then find where "feature id=" starts just after the "site" node. Find the "/site" tag and copy all the text between them, paste to another file just before the "/site" tag.
[You can do the similiar also marked feature tags with artifacts.xml]

5 when merging i suggest you to make a new directory and when finished please remember copy the merged file to the one where should it be and overwrite. [I mean where it comes from]
Although not merge "platform.xml" will not cause any functional errors, it will make the About dialog with no button -- to ugly yeah?
[= =|||]Ugly is caused by the artifacts.xml in the installation directory...

6 Open all the package, find "plugins" and "features" directories.now extract!
first extract the one you want most. I extracted JEE package.
then extract the other ones. I don't see any problem whether Overwrite the ones or not.

7 do open a console window, and locale in the installation directory, and then execute "eclipse.exe".

Well, somebody ask me why i paid no attention to the Artifacts.xml in the installation directory. That's because Eclipse will never check the file. It seems to be when you want to update using zip files -- however this way is blocked for lacking site.xml file now.

Then guys, wait a several minutes for eclipse to do some sorting and cleaning job for the merged configurations.. and install your plugins!

INFO: if you face some problems after install a new plugin and restart.. that is because you haven't finish a complete artifacts.xml merging.
You may delete all the artifacts.xml 's header [document start to the "artifacts size = '{Number}'"] and its bottom [from "/artifacts" to document end]. just merge the left content. and make one file just contains the header and bottom, paste the merged one in.
Eh..maybe you can calculate the {Number}s' sum and correct the one in the final document.

Comment: the original article is here in Chinese:   http://bbs.xidian.edu.cn/viewthread.php?tid=53399

Answer (score 4):

Get one of the packages from [their site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and use the `Install new software...` feature under the help menu.

I think the most straightforward way to get the modules for all of the languages to play nicely together, though I admire your DIY spirit.

Comment: Oh, Because of the Great Network Firewall of China, this job will take at least one week...

Comment: @Serenade Do you have source in those zips or is it binaries?  They also distribute the binaries in .zip files, so if you have one of those, you can open it up and start using it.  Unfortunate that you have such measures in place.  I don't know if Eclipse would have local mirrors...

Comment: more info: unzipping things into plugins and features hasn't worked since 3.4 (Ganymede).  Unzipping over older installs has never worked.  In Helios, you must use `Install new software...`

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I try Yoxos and it simply solves my problem.

Comment: @Serenade Glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Yoxos](http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start) for building your custom Eclipse distribution.